# 400 Bad Request When Adding Member to MailChimp List

Tags: php, laravel-5, guzzle, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am sending a `POST` request to [the following resource](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/) and getting a 400. I understand [what the error means](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/), but still am unsure why I'm getting it when a `GET` request to the same resource works.

```
/lists/{list_id}/members
```

Here is a exerpt of the code:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->request('POST', // <-- Drop in a GET here and it works, other than it's not the behavior I need.
    env('MAILCHIMP_API_URL') . 'lists/' . env('MAILCHIMP_LIST_KEY') . '/members',
    [
        'auth'  => ['app', env('MAILCHIMP_API_KEY')],
        'query' => [
            'email_address' => 'donnie@test.com',
            'email_type'    => 'html',
            'status'        => 'subscribed',
        ]
    ]);

dd($response->getStatusCode());
```

Response

```
Client error: `POST https://XXXX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/XXXX/members?email_address=donnie%40test.com&email_type=html&status=subscribed`
resulted in a `400 Bad Request`
response: {
  "type": "http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/",
  "title": "Invalid Resource",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array.",
  "instance": "f32e7076-b970-4f5c-82c6-eec5875e83b4",
  "errors": [{
    "field": "",
    "message": "Schema describes object, NULL found instead"
  }]
}
```

Comment: Can you show the entire response? This normally happens when the user is already in the list (maybe unsubscribed).

Comment: The response is added to the post.

Comment: Can you fix the formatting? I'm looking for the `detail` index in the response.

Comment: Fixed. The response is truncated just as is shown in the post, too.

Comment: Could you dump it through `var_dump` instead? I think `dd` truncates it. Either that or `dd` the `detail` index.

Comment: Wrap the statement in a try catch so you can dump it properly.

Comment: The full response is now shown.

Comment: Why are you using POST here, Seeing that you're using Guzzle's `new \GuzzleHttp\Client()` the documentation specifically shows to use a GET method http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

Comment: @Fred-ii- Because that example you linked to is for a `GET` request, not a `POST`...

Comment: @JimWright Oh, I see. Nice to see that you posted a solution for the OP Jim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending a `POST` request with `query` parameters. You need to send `JSON` encoded body!

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->request('POST', // <-- Drop in a GET here and it works, other than it's not the behavior I need.
    env('MAILCHIMP_API_URL') . 'lists/' . env('MAILCHIMP_LIST_KEY') . '/members',
    [
        'auth'  => ['app', env('MAILCHIMP_API_KEY')],
        'json' => [
            'email_address' => 'donnie@test.com',
            'email_type'    => 'html',
            'status'        => 'subscribed',
        ]
    ]);

dd($response->getStatusCode());
```